# Avoiding a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, optimization, for-loop

I am trying to avoid a loop in R. But I am having difficulties. At the moment this is the code that I have but I would really like to know if there is a direct way to do it (no loop). Triangle is just a IxJ matrix

```
I = 10
J = 10
xi <- rep(0,J) 
xi[1] <- 1
for(j  in 2:J){
  xi[j]<-(1/(I-j+1))*sum(log(Triangle[1:(I-j+1),j]/Triangle[1:(I-j+1),j-1]))
}
```

Comment: Could you tell more what you want to achieve with that code? Maybe desired output or equation?

Comment: I believe not, because your equation involves `1:(j+stuff)` and you can't vectorize that.

Comment: I am trying to fill the vector xi with the formula,               xi[j]<-(1/(I-j+1))*sum(log(Triangle[1:(I-j+1),j]/Triangle[1:(I-j+1),j-1]))          But i was wondering if I could use some kind of ":" to avoid the loop here

Comment: Well, there's always the `vectorize` function.  You'd have to run a time trial to see if it saves you anything in this simple case.

Comment: But how would I use the vectorize function here?

Comment: `xfun<-function(j) (1/(I-j+1))*sum(log(Triangle[1:(I-j+1),j]/Triangle[1:(I-j+1),j-1])) ; vxfun <- Vectorize(xfun)`  That's not exactly what you want since I didn't allow for varying `I,J` but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized solution. However, this does not seem to improve efficiency.

```
mat <- matrix(NA, nrow=I, ncol=J)
smat1 <- cbind(FALSE, rbind(lower.tri(matrix(nrow=I-1, ncol=J-1), diag=TRUE)[(I-1):1,], FALSE))
smat2 <- lower.tri(matrix(nrow=I, ncol=J))[I:1,]
mat[smat1] <- Triangle[smat1] / Triangle[smat2]
res <- c(1, colMeans(log(mat), na.rm=TRUE)[-1])
```